# Alternative to pst-gr3d

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

I am unable to get [pst-gr3d](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-gr3d) to work with pdftex. Is there an alternative that will allow me to easily define a cube structure? I've looked at TikZ alternatives but they require me to define each sub cube in the structure, which is very time consuming.

Comment: run it with `xelatex` or use package `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: auto-pst-pdf worked. Thanks @Herbert.

Comment: @Herbert an answer?